# State variable is not updated after getting data from SharedPreferences

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following problem: there's a state class:

```
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  String _name = "David";

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getNameFromPreferences();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

...

child: Text(
                  "Good Morning, \n"+_name,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 28, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
          )
      }
```

...........................

```
void getNameFromPreferences() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    _name = prefs.getString(Strings.nameKey);
    log(_name);
  }
```

So, here you can see that I'm trying to get data from preferences and set it to variable in state. I watched in logs, that this data is really exists and that it sets to `_name` almost in the moment. But on the screen I still see default value `David` but not my data from `SharedPreferences`. So, why such situation happens?

Comment: You might want to consider using `FutureBuilder` whenever you get result asynchronusly. Or if you want to follow below mentioned answers make sure you validate `_name` (e.g. if (isBlank(_name))  'Good Morning' else 'Good Morning, $_name')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change your code as follow,

```
getNameFromPreferences() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    _name = prefs.getString(Strings.nameKey);
    log(_name);
    setState(() {});
  }
```

This will solve your issue.

> Because sharedprefs package in async manner. so it takes some time to configure your data. till then your build method gets built. So, you have to use setState again to rebuild your view to render ui changes.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't call `setState()`.

```
void getNameFromPreferences() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    _name = prefs.getString(Strings.nameKey);
    log(_name);
    setState(() {}); // add this
}
```